# What kind of query i need to compare this values

Tags: mysql

I wanted to add "ID_CHOOSE2", "ID_CHOOSE3" etc to each user, what kind of query would I have to create for it to be correct? I Tried use "OR":

```
ON w.ID_CHOOSE OR w.ID_CHOOSE2 = m.ID_PERSON AND m.ID_CHOOSE OR m.ID_CHOOSE2 = w.ID_PERSON
```

And

```
ON (w.ID_CHOOSE = m.ID_PERSON AND m.ID_CHOOSE = w.ID_PERSON)
OR (w.ID_CHOOSE2 = m.ID_PERSON AND m.ID_CHOOSE2 = w.ID_PERSON)
```

As you can see, the query is not working well because it is poorly structured.

I mean a comparison of the type: A person chose some person (choose) and another (choose2). Check if the other person chose the first person in all their choices (choose, choose2 etc). If so, they match, if not, do not display and check others people. I want output like:

```
TOM W  | KATE B
MARK K | KATE B
MARK K | ALEX S
```

My code with desc: https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xz4552uv

-- EDIT FOR MORE INFO ---
I have a table with men and women (users)
And two other tables containing the choices of men and women

Now I would like to find a match (who matches whom based on choices in "Choose" columns - they are not always in sequence. Sometimes it's 3,2,1 and sometimes it's 1,3,2)
This is illustrated in the example below:

ID_PERSON MAN:

```
1 - JACK  - Choose: 1,3,2 (Mary, Emily, Lilly)
2 - TOM   - Choose: 1,2,3 (Mary, Lilly, Emily)
3 - HARRY - Choose: 2,1   (Lilly, Mary)
```

```
| ID | ID_PERSON | ID_CHOOSE | ID_CHOOSE2 | ID_CHOOSE3  |
| 1  |      1    |     1     |     3      |     2       | 
| ID | ID_PERSON | ID_CHOOSE | ID_CHOOSE2 | ID_CHOOSE3  |
| 2  |      2    |     1     |     2      |     3       | 
| ID | ID_PERSON | ID_CHOOSE | ID_CHOOSE2 | ID_CHOOSE3  |
| 3  |      3    |     2     |     1      | NULL(empty) |
```

ID_PERSON WOMAN:

```
1 - Mary  - Choose: 3,1,2 (Harry, Tom, Jack)
2 - Lilly - Choose: 1,2   (Jack, Harry)
3 - Emily - Choose: 1,2,3 (Jack, Tom, Harry)
```

```
| ID | ID_PERSON | ID_CHOOSE | ID_CHOOSE2  | ID_CHOOSE3 |
| 1  |      1    |     3     |     1       |     2      | 
| ID | ID_PERSON | ID_CHOOSE | ID_CHOOSE2  | ID_CHOOSE3 |
| 2  |      2    |     1     | NULL(empty) |     2      | 
| ID | ID_PERSON | ID_CHOOSE | ID_CHOOSE2  | ID_CHOOSE3 |
| 3  |      3    |     1     |     2       |     3      |
```

```
Match:
JACK  Matched with: Mary, Emily, Lilly
TOM   Matched with: Mary, Emily
Harry Matched with: Lilly, Harry
```

Thanks

Comment: Your present data structure could be more efficiently stored in one table.

Comment: I get the desired result when I use your condition with the parentheses. https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3xz4rmxx2

Comment: @Barmar. Yes i know because man_match is ('1', '3', '2', '1') and it compare with query, but when change it to ('1', '3', '1', '2') that code not working despite this reordering, the people still matched. :)

Comment: It's hard to understand your description of what you're trying to do. Please add an example to the question that shows the incorrect and desired results.

Comment: @Kendle Could you give an example on my code above to make it work even on one table? A man picks several women, women picks a few men, and I'd like to find all the matches.

Comment: @Barmar I edited my post and add more info

Comment: All those `ID_CHOOSEn` columns are an anti-pattern. You should normalize by putting each choice in a separate row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative schéma.
See dbFiddle link below.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM users;
> SELECT * FROM choices;
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | name     | gender
> --: | :------- | :-----
> 101 | KATE B   | F     
> 102 | ALEX S   | F     
> 203 | TOM W    | M     
> 204 | MARK K   | M     
> 205 | DENNIS A | M     
>
> chid | chooser | choice
> ---: | ------: | -----:
>    1 |     203 |    101
>    2 |     203 |    102
>    3 |     204 |    102
>    4 |     204 |    101
>    5 |     101 |    203
>    6 |     101 |    204
>    7 |     102 |    204
>    8 |     102 |    205
> ```

> ```
> select 
> m.id, m.name man,
> f.id, f.name woman
> from
> choices c 
> join choices s 
> on c.chooser = s.choice
> left join users m on m.id = c.chooser
> left join users f on f.id = c.choice
> where s.chooser = c.choice
> and m.gender = 'M'
> and f.gender = 'F';
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | man    |  id | woman 
> --: | :----- | --: | :-----
> 203 | TOM W  | 101 | KATE B
> 204 | MARK K | 101 | KATE B
> 204 | MARK K | 102 | ALEX S
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9d388ea5adbc2102ba4f022c937d6950)*

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answer. It works perfect after change to f.name. From this query its possible to Send ONE email to "MARK K" which will contain emails to "KATE B" and "ALEX S"? for ex. to: "MARK K" an email content: Hi "MARK K" You Matched with "KATE B" Her email: " kateb@gmail.com "and" ALEX S "Her email:" alexs@gmail.com "So as not to send two separate emails to the same person with matches
But at the same time to "KATE B" Send a message matches are "MARK K" and "TOM W"? [DB FIDDLE LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cae2e07eac3719ec0aa3b816b601554d) How to build that query?

Comment: Thanks - I've corrected that, and the DBfiddle link